# Deploying Play project as a service

Tags: java, ssh, web-applications, playframework-2.0, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a java web app built using Play.
This [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying) provides a detailed instructions on how to do that.

I successfully managed to follow the instructions to deploy play using the dist command. To run the app I used the command below

`play-projects-test-play-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/play-projects-test-play`

The app is deployed on an `Oracle Linux Server release 7.2` which I am connected to through ssh.

However my issue is that when terminating ssh connection would go offline as well. How do I run the it as a service (e.g. service mongod start) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the process in background using [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

```
nohup ./play-projects-test-play> /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Also you can use [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) as alternative

```
screen -A -m -d -S screenname ./play-projects-test-play &
```

**note:** you need to install screen

```
yum install screen
```